# Flutter Firebase Push Notification image does not appear in IOS notification panel

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Flutter firebase_messaging library.
I can display firebase push notification image in Android notification panel (system notification) like below, but I can't display it in IOS notification panel
[enter image description here](https://ibb.co/YWdz4jW)

I did notification service extension

[notification service extension image](https://ibb.co/kQBWLk0)

Comment: please refer to this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/8277640-push-notifications-tutorial-for-ios-rich-push-notifications

Answer (score 1):

After adding the Notification Service Extension (firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration), make sure the **target iOS of the extension** is lower than your device iOS version.

For example if you device iOS is 15.0, set the target version to 12.0.

In Xcode navigator click "Runner", under TARGETS select the new extension, under General tab go to Deployment info, change iOS target

Comment: OMG ! Thank you so much for your answer ! I never found that crucial information elsewhere until here  :O